# How to pass data from View to Controller, when View was genereted by reflection object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, reflection, parameter-passing

**Environment:**

ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 and Library .NET Standard

**Goals:**

1. Create object from DLL (dll can be changed at any moment) with no constant structure, ex. class Obj{ int, string, string}, but another dll will has class Obj {int, int, int}.
2. Pass this object to view.
3. Generate single "form box" without knowing what properties have object. ex. string => textbox, bool => checkbox etc.
4. Pass this data to method/controller/api.

**My problem:**

On that moment I can first three points, but I can't pass data to the Controller. I tried debug it, but method Index(int x, int y) always is call with params x = 0, y = 0.

**Code:**

*HomeController.cs*

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Assembly dllAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + 
                                                 "\\TestLib.dll");
        Type dllType = dllAssembly.GetType("TestLib.TestModel");
        tempObj = Activator.CreateInstance(dllType);

        ViewBag.Message = tempObj;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(int x, int y)
    {
        Assembly dllAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + 
                                                 "\\TestLib.dll");
        Type dllType = dllAssembly.GetType("TestLib.TestModel");
        tempObj = Activator.CreateInstance(dllType);

        dllType.GetProperty("X").SetValue(tempObj, x);
        dllType.GetProperty("Y").SetValue(tempObj, y);

        ViewBag.Message = tempObj;
        return View();
    }
```

*TestModel.cs*

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Range(0, 10)]
    public int X { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 10)]
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

*Index.cshtml*

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    var data = ViewBag.Message;
}

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => data)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

*Generated html*

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
<div class="editor-label">
<label for="data_X">X</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-range="The field X must be between 0 and 10." data-val-range-max="10" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="The X field is required." id="data_X" name="data.X" type="number" value="0"> 
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="data.X" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
<label for="data_Y">Y</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-range="The field Y must be between 0 and 10." data-val-range-max="10" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="The Y field is required." id="data_Y" name="data.Y" type="number" value="0"> 
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="data.Y" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<input type="submit">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="deleted">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your generated html it seems your controller needs to accept parameters "`data.X`" and "`data.Y`", which is not going to work with parameter names due to obvious reasons.

You could get the bulk form data by chaging your method to accept [`IFormCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformcollection?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```cs
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(IFormCollection collection)
        {
            Assembly dllAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + 
                                                 "\\TestLib.dll");
            Type dllType = dllAssembly.GetType("TestLib.TestModel");
            tempObj = Activator.CreateInstance(dllType);

            dllType.GetProperty("X").SetValue(tempObj, int.Parse(collection["data.X"]));
            dllType.GetProperty("Y").SetValue(tempObj, int.Parse(collection["data.Y"]));

            ViewBag.Message = tempObj;
            return View();
        }
```

you could try and explore [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in further detail as well.